# Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, maven-3, nexus, artifact

I'm trying to deploy the artifacts , lets say "demo.war" into my remote nexus and facing following issue. We recently upgraded our plugins/jenkins (before this the pipeline job was working fine).
Not sure what went wrong still couldn't resolve this error.
Could anyone spot the error?please.

```
Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact :demo:war:1.0.1 from/to releases (http://demo_server_url:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases): Failed to transfer file: http://demo_server_url:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/demo-server/1.0.1/demo-1.0.1.war. Return code is: 500, ReasonPhrase:Server Error.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: Uploading file demo.war failed.
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: typically an error 500 suggests that there is a problem on the server side (nexus) rather then on the client. Did you check your nexus logs?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. yeah and here is the log error message:
```
INFO  [qtp949800452-3045] admin org.sonatype.nexus.error.reporting.DefaultErrorReportingManager - Detected Error in Nexus: The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request. Skipping problem report generation because reporting is not enabled
```

Comment: grep "ERROR" nexus.log
2019-09-19 09:57:00 ERROR [qtp949800452-3692] admin org.sonatype.nexus.rest.ContentPlexusResource - Got exception during processing request "PUT http://demo_server_url:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/demo-server/1.0.1/demo-server-1.0.1.war":

Comment: The top of the stack doesn't show the reason... look for the "caused by" exception.